# Dynamic UITextView size based on content in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uitextview

I don't suppose someone could guide me on the proper way to dynamically size a UITextView while still using Auto-Layout?  Using Swift, that is.

I've tried programmatically adjusting the bottom constraints in attempt to get the UITextView to hug the content.  But I'm not sure how to get the height of the content of the UITextView?

I'm attempting to load data into UITextView fields, then, dynamically adjust them to look neat.

```
@IBOutlet weak var serviceDescriptionTextViewBottomGuide: NSLayoutConstraint! 

override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.activityName.text = serviceCodes[selectionValue]
        self.serviceDescriptionTextView.text = serviceDescription[selectionValue]
        self.whenToUseDescriptionTextView.text = whenToUseCode[selectionValue]

        self.serviceDescriptionTextViewBottomGuide?.constant += x
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is scrolling enabled in the UITextView?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Disable scrolling and do not put any other constraint that can dictate the height of UITextView. Let me know it that works.

Comment: I will add it as answer and please accept it so that in future people may find it useful.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Disable scrolling and do not put any other constraint that can dictate the height of UITextView.

Answer (score 2):

This is right but I also had to write:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // Replace with your actual estimation
    // Automatic dimensions to tell the table view to use dynamic height
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

See more:

https://pontifex.azurewebsites.net/self-sizing-uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-in-ios-8/

Comment: Just wanted to add something to this answer. do not use when using rowHeight (tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `IBOutlet` for any constraint you want to vary programmatically. Then vary the constraint via its NSLayoutConstraint's `constant` property in the code via its outletted reference. That works pretty well.  You can vary width, hight and position that way. You cannot *modify* NSLayoutConstraint's `multiplier` property though (it's readonly).  But that doesn't matter, because what you could accomplish via definining a constraint's multiplier property in Interface Builder (to get a proportional value), you can alternatively accomplish by performing the math in your code and modifying the `constant` property.

An alternative approach is, you can disable the resizing mask translation (e.g.the `UIView` `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property set to nil) and create your constraints from scratch programmatically, for which the recommended approach (easier to use) is called *visual format*.  But creating constraints totally programmatically is more work than using Interface Builder Autolayout to create a rough draft of your views, and then tweaking select constraints programmatically after the fact, at least in typical simple cases.

Comment: I made a *bunch* of edits, but I'm done, so please scan to see if something changed that is valuable info for you.

Comment: First, to show code blocks in comments just use a 'back apostrophe' before and after (not 'code').  For example \`mycode\`

Comment: I had a bad question; didn't include what I tried. But, I was attempting the first method you mention. Sadly, I'm not sure where to find the content size? I tried, 
`self.serviceDescriptionTextViewBottomGuide?.constant = self.whenToUseDescriptionTextView.contentSize.height`

Comment: Oh, I think someone else can probably help you with the answer to that. I would have to do some research to figure it out.