# GrowingTextView or expandable textview inside UItableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wish to implement an expandable textview inside the table cell, I found the GrowingTextView but I still failed to implement.I need to get input from user and the cell will auto resize when the users typing. Is there any easier implementation or guide on this? Thanks all

[image]

Comment: simple, just set the bottom constraint of the textview to the bottom of the cell, and set textview.isScrollEnabled = false. your cell height must be auto though

Comment: @koropok you try before? I need to get the user input and the cell will auto resize when the user typing

Comment: yes i did that before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403241/dynamic-uitextview-size-based-on-content-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

Actually you dont need 3rd party library to do this.

1. Change your GrowingTextView to `UILabel`
2. Config you UILabel to `Top, Left, Right, and Bottom` to the cell, and make "Title" label dependent on the UILabel
   this is important because the cell size is dependant of the content of UILabel.
3. Set `numberOfLines` to 0 and
4. Set `lineBreakMode` to `word wrapping` or `character warpping`
5. Set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150 // or wtever you found reasonable`

For task like these i suggest you can do more research on Internet instead of using a 3rd party library so fast, the keyword here is dynamic table view cell which by searching on Google there are lots of tutorials helping you out without using 3rd party library.

Comment: Edison thanks for the reply, but I need to use textview because we need to get input from the user, and the cell will auto resize when the users typing in more texts

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with native UITextView.

Implement this in the text view's delegate

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    CGRect oldFrame = textView.frame;
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(yourTextViewWidth, MAXFLOAT);

    CGRect rect = [textView.text boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textView.font} context:nil];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.size.width, size.height + 5)];
    // These 2 lines to force UITableView to redo the height calculation.
    [self.yourTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.yourTableView endUpdates];
}
```

Then, implement this in the table view's delegate

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *yourTextViewText; 
 // You get the text either from the same way you did in cellForRowAtIndexPath dataSource 
 // or if you already referenced UITextView as your property you can easily retrieve the text by calling self.yourTextView.text        
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(yourTextViewWidth, MAXFLOAT);

    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:yourFontSize]} context:nil];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, yourDefaultCellHeight);
    return height + 5;
}
```

**UPDATE** Swift version converted by Swiftify v4.1.6738 - https://objectivec2swift.com/

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let oldFrame: CGRect = textView.frame
    let constraint = CGSize(width: yourTextViewWidth, height: MAXFLOAT)
    let rect: CGRect = textView.text.boundingRect(with: constraint, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: textView.font], context: nil)
    let size = CGSize(width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height)
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: oldFrame.origin.x, y: oldFrame.origin.y, width: oldFrame.size.width, height: size.height + 5)
    // These 2 lines to force UITableView to redo the height calculation.
    yourTableView.beginUpdates()
    yourTableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let yourTextViewText: String
        // You get the text either from the same way you did in cellForRowAtIndexPath dataSource 
        // or if you already referenced UITextView as your property you can easily retrieve the text by calling self.yourTextView.text        
    let constraint = CGSize(width: yourTextViewWidth, height: MAXFLOAT)
    let rect: CGRect = text.boundingRect(with: constraint, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: yourFontSize)], context: nil)
    let size = CGSize(width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height)
    let height: CGFloat = max(size.height, yourDefaultCellHeight)
    return height + 5
}
```

Comment: Is there any Swift version available? Because I new to Swift and not really familiar with Obj-C

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I'm not quite familiar with Swift unfortunately so I used the online converter. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks man, may I ask you some question? the textview is inside the cell, so the IBoutlet is registered in the cell file, then how should I refer it on the view controller file? because the textview delegate are done in the view controller right?

Comment: Sure go ahead .

Comment: You can easily assign its delegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath to self. For example: yourCustomCellClass.yourTextViewOutlet.delegate = self

Comment: let me try ya..if got anything I will ask you again

Comment: I cannot refer the textview in the textViewDidChange, inside cellforRow its easier to access.

Comment: what do you mean?